# Unique Constraint NFT, only 1 allowed per Address?

Tags: nft, identity

Is it possible to program an NFT to only allow 1 copy of it per address?

For example if Address #1 and #2 both already have 1 copy of this NFT, if Address #1 tries to send theirs to Address #2, it should fail to send.

Would this involve overriding the default behavior of "transferFrom" ERC721?

Any suggestions on where to look on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would override the default behavior of `_transferFrom` method, but is not clear what you mean by "1 copy of this NFT". Each NFT has its own token ID, did you mean to check if actually Address #2 is owning already 1 NFT, no matter the token ID?
You may make use of ERC721's **balanceOf()** or **tokenOfOwnerByIndex()** methods.

Comment: I'm just now learning about NFTs and their nuances. My goal is to 1) send the same type of NFT to many addresses and 2) each copy of that NFT has a unique id that I can custom define so that 3) it is used just like an identity management system, no 2 users (addresses) can have the same "name" metadata in the NFT and no 1 user (address) can have more than 1 of this type of NFT in their address.

Comment: So you want to allow a single token defined by a metadata collection to be owned by an address. If yes, you can either go with the classic tokenURI implementation, where each minted token will have its own token URI (containing the JSON of the metadata). Then you can loop through all tokens owned by the address which should receive a token and check if the token URI already exists.

Comment: Or use CryptoKitties idea of implementing the "genes" which is a kind of hashing of all metadata properties so when a token is about to be transferred to an address, the transfer method would check if the hash of the properties is already in the list of the owned tokens

Comment: "genes" sounds like a neat trick, will look into that, thanks :)